# Solve for $y'\cos{y}=\sin(x+y)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve for $y'\cos{y}=\sin(x+y)$

My attempt

$$y'\cos{y}=\sin x \cos y + \cos x \sin y$$

Divide both side by $\cos y$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sin x + \cos x \tan y$$

Integrate both sides and I got

$$y = -\cos x + \int \cos x \tan y \,dx$$

As [Maximilian Janisch](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/631742/maximilian-janisch) said that $\int\cos() \tan(())d≠\sin() \tan(())$ I didn't know what to do next.

Comment: How come multiplying the LHS by dx give you dy?

Comment: @UnnayanUpadhyay $y' = \frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: "How can I isolate for $y$?" -- It is worth noting you won't always be able to. Sometimes you're just stuck with an implicit solution.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer how about my attempt? Did I do the right way or not?

Comment: It is in my opinion a bad habit to "multiply with $dx$" because you are in fact applying the fundamental Theorem of calculus. Here, there is also a mistake: $y$ depends on $x$ so $$\int \cos(x)\tan(y(x))\,\mathrm dx\neq \sin(x)\tan(y(x))$$ in general. I am also not sure if there is a nice closed form for $y$ 

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch So the solution just $$y = -\cos x  + \int \cos x \tan y \,dx$$?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that any function $y$ which satisfies this new equation will also satisfy the original one. However, the new equation does in my opinion not give any more insight than the original obe

Comment: I suppose you could obtain a power series solution with $y=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ to give $$\small\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)a_{n+1}x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}+\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n2^{2n+2}(2^{2n+2}-1)B_{2n+2}\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\right)^{2n+1}}{(2n+2)!}\right),$$ valid for $|x|<\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, power series solution seems to be the only way.

Writing
$$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n$$ the very first terms would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & t \\
 2 & t^3+t+1 \\
 3 & 3 t^5+4 t^3+t^2+1 \\
 4 & 15 t^7+27 t^5+7 t^4+9 t^3+8 t^2-3 t \\
 5 & 105 t^9+240 t^7+63 t^6+144 t^5+103 t^4+6 t^3+34 t^2-2 t-6 \\
 6 & 945 t^{11}+2625 t^9+693 t^8+2250 t^7+1476 t^6+566 t^5+847 t^4+49 t^3+48 t^2+53
   t-15
\end{array}
\right)$$ where $t=\tan(a_0)$.

Not very funny, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$y'\cos y=\sin(x+y)$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}\cos y=\sin(x+y)$

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{\cos y}{\sin(x+y)}$

Let $u=x+y$ ,

Then $x=u-y$

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{du}{dy}-1$

$\therefore\dfrac{du}{dy}-1=\dfrac{\cos y}{\sin u}$

$\dfrac{du}{dy}=\dfrac{\cos y}{\sin u}+1$

$\dfrac{du}{dy}=\dfrac{\sin u+\cos y}{\sin u}$

$(\sin u+\cos y)\dfrac{dy}{du}=\sin u$